# Find and replace multiple occurrences of a word in a long string

Tags: swift

I'm parsing through some HTML files and tagging while I write the markdown.

For a simplified example:

```
var String = "This is a text <int=8-10, This is some more text.><int=1-7, This is some alt text.>"
```

Let's say for starters I want to match every `<int=` in this string and remove it. Is there an efficient way to do this in Swift right now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
myString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("<int=", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)
```

`stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString` ([documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:options:range:)) will replace a substring with another substring (in this case empty `""`).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method to get ranges of substrings as an array:

```
(
    "NSRange: {538, 1}",
    "NSRange: {848, 1}",
    "NSRange: {1183, 1}",
    "NSRange: {1418, 1}"
)

func rangesOfString(searchString: String,  attrStr : NSMutableAttributedString) -> NSArray
    {
        var inputLength = count(attrStr.string)
        var searchLength = count(searchString)
        var range = NSRange(location: 0, length: attrStr.length)

        var results = NSMutableArray()
        while (range.location != NSNotFound) {
            range = (attrStr.string as NSString).rangeOfString(searchString, options: nil, range: range)
            if (range.location != NSNotFound) {
                results.addObject(NSRange(location: range.location, length: searchLength))
                range = NSRange(location: range.location + range.length, length: inputLength - (range.location + range.length))
            }
        }
        return results as NSArray
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For your information, this function is now called:

```
replacingOccurrences(of: String, with: String, options: String.CompareOptions, range: Range<String.Index>?)
```

Comment: how can I give range expression ?